# bigquery federated data sources command line external_table_definition - does it work?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to create an external table in bigquery via command line as is referenced here:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/federated-data-sources#cli

But even the example provided doesn't work:
bq mk --project_id= --external_table_definition=/tmp/wikipedia .wikipedia

results in this error message:
FATAL Flags parsing error: Unknown command line flag 'external_table_definition'

I am using GCloud SDK version 97.0.0 and it says that my bq version is 2.0.18 so I think I am up to date.

Has anyone successfully used this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bq version` 2.0.18 is quite old - the current version is 2.0.22.  Have you tried updating with `gcloud components update`?

I am able to pass an external_table_definition to the mk command with `bq version` 2.0.22.

---

Correction: After investigating a bit more closely, `gcloud -v` says the current version of bq is 2.0.18, but `bq version` should return 2.0.22 for the most recent version.  So 2.0.18 *could* be the most recent, depending on where you are looking.

Comment: I ran gcloud components update and it says all components up to date. However when I run bq version, it returns 2.0.17.   There no longer appears to be a separate download for just bq. It all comes through the gcloud sdk.   So how do I get the newer version of bq?

Comment: `gcloud components update` should do the trick.  Are you sure you're using the bq binary packaged with gcloud, and not a older bq installed separately?  The bq packaged with gcloud should be in a /bin directory nearby the gcloud binary.

Comment: yeah, that was it, I was using the older bq stand alone install.  thanks so much for your help.